# Should class methods be made static in all cases if they don't use absolutely any class fields?

Tags: java, static-methods

Should class methods be made static in all cases if they don't use absolutely any class fields?

Are there exceptions? According to my logic, if a class method does not use any of its fields, then it must be static. Right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/when-to-use-static-methods)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: So, whats still missing after you visit the given link?

Comment: You don't need to create an object to use any of its method/field when you declare that method/field static. For better understanding see this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html#:~:text=Fields%20that%20have%20the%20static,one%20fixed%20location%20in%20memory.

Comment: Timor, specific answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method doesn't use any instance variables in it's containing class then it doesn't **have** to be static, but it **should** be.  As a general rule, if a method doesn't require a class instantiation to be used then it should be extracted to a utility class/interface as a static method.

Comment: Should be according to who or what?